# throw Error('msg') vs throw new Error('msg')

Tags: javascript, exception

```
var err1 = Error('message');
var err2 = new Error('message');
```

What's the difference? Looking at them in the chrome console, they look identical. Same properties on the object and the same `__proto__` chain. Almost seems like `Error` acts like a factory.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: All the native constructors are defined in ECMAScript, including their respective behavior when invoked without `new`.

Comment: See also [When is `new Error()` better than `Error()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38759428/1048572)

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Both are fine; this is explicitly stated in [the specification](https://es5.github.io/#x15.11.1):

> ... Thus the function call `Error(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Error(…)` with the same arguments.

Comment: Is this true in ES6 as well?

Comment: Yes.  For current docs see: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-error-constructor

Comment: @paulmelnikow - Yes. Backward compatibility is TC39's highest priority. The mantra is "don't break the web."

Answer (score 25):

`Error` does act like a factory, like some other native constructors: `Array`, `Object`, etc. all check something like `if (!(this instanceof Array)) { return new Array(arguments); }`. (But note that `String(x)` and `new String(x)` are very different, and likewise for `Number` and `Boolean`.)

That said, in case of an error, it's not even required to throw an `Error` object... `throw 'Bad things happened';` will work, too
You can even throw an object literal for debugging:

```
throw {message:"You've been a naughty boy",
       context: this,
       args: arguments,
       more:'More custom info here'};
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully agree. `String("abc")` does not create a `String` object, whereas `new String("abc")` does.

Comment: @pimvdb: true, I've changed it to `Object` => `Object('foo')` returns a string object... come to thing of it _almost all native constructors_ is a bit wrong... `Number`, `Boolean`,`Date`,`String` all don't...`Array`, `Object` and `Error` do, but `Event` and all `DOMxxxx`-api constructors throw errors

Comment: I also think `new Array(arguments)` does not do exactly what `Array(1, 2, 3)` does. But probably I'm just nitpicking :)

Comment: @pimvdb: It probably doesn't, no. Then again: I always advise against the use of `new Array()`, for obvious reasons

Comment: Complementary with regard to throwing strings: [A string is not an error](http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/)

Comment: @alex: Granted, throwing non-`Error` instances (or string literals) looses the stack-trace. Just a nit-pick on the linked article: `arguments.callee` is forbidden in strict mode

Comment: _“You can even throw an object literal for debugging”_ — or simply use `debugger;` or [`console.trace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace).