# Can I throw error in an async function?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I am using `async/await` in my Node.js project. And in some places I need to return an error from `async` function. If I'd use Promises, I could've accomplish it this way:

```
function promiseFunc() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    return rej(new Error('some error'))
  })
}
```

But I'm using `async` function, so no `res` and `rej` methods are there.
So, the question: can I `throw` errors in `async` functions? Or is it considered a good/bad practice?

An example of what I want to do:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
  throw new Error('some another error')
}
```

I can also rewrite it this way:

```
async function anotherAsyncFunc() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('we need more errors!'))
}
```

but the first one looks more clear to me, and I'm not sure which one should I use.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I would do:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
  try {
    await somePromise();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

But I think it comes to personal preference I guess? You could always return `Promise.reject(new Error(error));`.

Comment: As of today, there is another link that may help: https://makandracards.com/makandra/43653-javascript-don-t-throw-exceptions-from-async-functions

Comment: Be aware that the provided link doesn't address `await`/`async` behavior, but asynchronous execution with promises. One of the beautiful things about `await`/`async` is that [exceptions thrown from `async` functions are wrapped in rejected promises automatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value), so it's perfectly safe to do so.

Comment: why `throw new Error(error)` instead of just `throw error` ?

Comment: some linters hate 'throw error'

Comment: "some linters hate 'throw error'" -- why? bad linter? Probably. You can leave out the `new`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13294683/145400.

Comment: @Dr.Jan-PhilipGehrcke But `error` is already of type Error. You really do not need to wrap it again into an error object.